# Set property 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ListPicker.ItemCountThreshold' threw an exception?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, exception

When I try and run my application through the emulator it breaks and I get this message

" Set property 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ListPicker.ItemCountThreshold' threw an exception. "

any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste you code, how your xaml looks like...

Comment: @BhavikGoyal http://postimage.org/image/sm8euct4t/ here, hope you can help Bhavik :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you should not use ListPickerItem directly; if you want to declare the items directly in XAML use string or any other class!

Check this sample:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="PhoneApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <toolkit:ListPicker ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly">
                <sys:String>Item 1</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Item 2</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Item 3</sys:String>
            </toolkit:ListPicker>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

As you can see here, all it takes is to not use ListPickerItem!

Also, remove the ItemCountThreshold property; that is a readonly property and shouldn't be set in XAML!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly".

Comment: I read that somewhere else too, but where do I have to look for ExpansionMode, I can't see it anywhere ?